# How to Compare datetime in Android

Tags: java, android, json, datetime, compare

I have dates, date1(now) and date2 which is returned in a JSON string say `2016-07-09 21:26:04`.

I want to compare those two dates something like

```
if(date1 < date2){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to compare two DateTime objects in Android:

```
 public void onDateSelected(DateTime dateSelected) {
    DateTime currentDateTime = new DateTime(); 

    try{
        // You can use any format to compare by spliting the dateTime 
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ");

        String str1 = dateSelected.toString();
        Date selectedDate = formatter.parse(str1);

        String str2 = currentDateTime.toString();
        Date currentDate = formatter.parse(str2);

        if (selectedDate.compareTo(currentDate)<0)
        {
            System.out.println("current date is Greater than my selected date");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("selected date is Greater than my current date"); 
        }

    }catch (ParseException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do this:

1. parse the in to Date objects
2. compare those

## Example:

```
 public static void main(String x[]) throws ParseException {
    String s1 = "2016-07-09 21:26:04";
    String s2 = "2006-07-09 21:26:04";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date d1 = sdf.parse(s1);
    Date d2 = sdf.parse(s2);
    int compareResult = d1.compareTo(d2);
    if (compareResult > 0) {
        System.out.println(s1 + " is younger than " + s2);
    } else if (compareResult < 0) {
        System.out.println(s1 + " is younger than " + s2);
    } else {
        System.out.println(s1 + " is equals than " + s2);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date today= new Date();

try {
        if (today.before(sdf.forrmat(json_string_date))) {
          // If start date is before end date.
          // Do your piece of code
         } 
    }catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```